# How Do I Get Unique IDs Efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, django

I want my users to each have a **unique** PIN and I achieve this using `uuid` as shown below:

```
from myApp.models import myUsers
import uuid

user_PIN = True
new_PIN = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
while user_PIN:
    try:
        user_PIN = myUsers.objects.get(pin = new_PIN)
    except myUsers.DoesNotExist:
        user_PIN = False
        new_PIN = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
    if not user_PIN:
        break
```

I want to be able to achieve two things here:

1. Do this efficiently
2. Remove **5, S, 0, O, 1, I** from the PIN

---

1. The `while` loop is to ensure that PINs are unique and, though, this does what I want effectively but I think it is not efficient as it will have to hit 100 million records if I have 100 million users.
   How can this be done in the most efficient way possible?
2. How do I achieve this uniqueness without the figures and letters mentioned above?

Comment: You might need to rethink the idea as a whole: `uuid.hex` returns a hexadecimal encoding so you only have `[0-9a-f]` in there. But  that gives you only `16^5 = 1,048,576` possible PINs from the start.

Comment: Okay, that's a thoughtful one. you have any idea on how best this can be done?

Comment: Have a look at the source code of some base62 encoder, like https://gist.github.com/adyliu/4494223 . You can modify the code and remove the lowercase letters and the 6 characters you specified.

Comment: `uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]` UUID is only universally unique if you use the entire UUID. If you are substringing it, you're better off just generating regular random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To requote my comment:

`uuid.hex` returns a hexadecimal encoding so you only have [0-9a-f] in there. Hence the requirement of removing the specified characters does not even come up.

However, using six hexadecimal digits, gives you only 16^6 = 16,777,216 possible PINs from the start. So with 100 million users, you **will** be running out of PINs (and have an endless loop).

In general I'd simply suggest choosing a large enough PIN space and dropping the requirement of having unique PINs if possible by the application design.

If you want 100 million+ users, you need *enough* room in your PIN space so that random number generation will not fail *too often*. This is rather vague, so let's come up with some numbers:

When you have a pin space of `n` and `u` existing users, generating a random number from `n` will yield an non-existing PIN `(n - u) / n` number of times. Add `l`-times looping and the probability of needing `l` loops is `((u / n) ** (t - 1)) * ((n - u) / n)` (i.e. the probability of selecting an existing number `t - 1` times and finally getting a non-existing number.

Now, with 6-character PINs and the mentioned characters dropped, your alphabet is probably something like:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijkmnpqrtuvwxyz2346789'
```

This gives you `30` characters and with 6-digit PINs you have `30 ** 6 = 
729,000,000` possible PINs. The first try to generate a unique PIN will thus fail around `1/7` of all possible cases when the user space reaches 100 million.

The bottleneck, however will be checking if the newly generated PIN already exists. Searching a number in a table of 100 million numbers multiple times is simply never a fast operation.

As for generating a unique string over an alphabet: Use `random.choice()`:

```
import random
pin_length = 6
random_pin = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in xrange(0, pin_length))
```

Comment: Would having all the PINs in a `.txt` file solve make any sense compared to searching through DB?

Comment: That would most likely make it slower. The database can do indexed search. Are you using the PINs are user IDs or why do they have to be unique?

Comment: I have an semi-anonymous chat room where users can choose not to show their username or display name.

Comment: And you expect 100 million concurrent users? I think you need a bigger boat ;-)

Comment: I just need the PINs to be unique. Blackberry did this. I mean unique PINs.

Comment: In that case, the PIN is more or less equal to your username and you only need to generate it when a new user is created.